# LaTeX beamer slide with symbols of people

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using LaTeX to make a presentation slide and I want to make a slide that shows students who are at a certain level. Basically I want to fill the latex slide with symbols of persons as shown in the image below:

[image]

And I want to enter the number of rows/columns of blue people and the number of both blue and red people.

Please help me! I am not even sure of where to start.

Answer (score 3):

You already know from your the [crosspost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494249/latex-beamer-slide-with-people-symbols), which you did not mention in your question, how to fill the slide with tikz shapes. For some other possibles shapes to use, here are a few suggestions:

Using the `tikzpeople` package, one could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,17}{\tikz{\node[person,shirt=red,scale=2] (B) at (0,0) {};} }%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{\tikz{\node[person,shirt=blue,scale=2] (B) at (0,0) {};} }

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And even better than people are ducks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,17}{\tikz{\duck[body=red,scale=0.5];} }%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{\tikz{\duck[body=blue,scale=0.5];} }

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or teddy bears:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzlings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,17}{\tikz{\bear[body=red,scale=0.5];} }%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{\tikz{\bear[body=blue,scale=0.5];} }

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so great but in Overleaf these packages can not be found and I even tried to load the .sty files manually. DO you have advice on this./

Comment: @bvowe Complain to overleaf, their texlive version is soooooooooooo outdated. If enough people complain, maybe they will finally update.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know of another way to implement them or is that something I should post as new question?

Comment: @bvowe As a bonus: if you convince them to use an up-to-date texlive installation, your beamer numbering problem could be solved in a single line.

Comment: @bvowe Uploading the .sty seems to work: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rkvyhtbsjhrt

Comment: So pretty ! how do i stack it say 5x5? for 5 cols and 5 rows

Comment: @bvowe Quickest way to get 5x5 is to restrict the width: `\centering
\begin{minipage}{.508\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,13}{\tikz{\duck[body=red,scale=0.5];}\hfill}%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{\tikz{\duck[body=blue,scale=0.5];}\hfill}
\end{minipage}`. Alternatively use 2 loops like in the other answers

Comment: thanks but can i specify this in any other way like a matrix or something? for example if i need 6x6 do i just keep changing the value of .508?

Comment: see how the first blue is misaligned with the red on the line above? is it possible to not have that be misaligned?

Comment: @bvowe As said, restricting the with is the quick way. For better results use the two loops from the answers you got in your cross-post on tex.se

Answer (score 1):

Tikz provides anything that is required: loop and math evaluation.
Here is a proposal. Assumes that your red/blue shapes are respectively in red.pdf and blue.pdf. I have replaced it by red and blue squares that are in files red.pdf and blue.pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\def\rowwidth{5}
\def\rownumber{3}
\def\threshold{12}
\parindent 0pt
\foreach \i in {0,...,\rownumber}{
  \foreach \j in {0,...,\rowwidth}{
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse((6*\i+\j>\threshold),"red","blue")}%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{\pgfmathresult}
  }
  \newline
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first lines just defines the drawing parameters (\rowwidth and \rownumber) and the value when color is changed (\threshold).
\foreach allows to do loops and \i (or \j) will take the successive values 0, 1, etc.
\pgfmathparse is the way tikz handles math expression. I use the ìfthenelse math function that evaluates its first parameter (6*\i+\j>12) and sets \pgfmatresult to either its second or third parameter.
Then just use this \pgfmathresult as the argument of an \includegraphics

But if your drawing is, for instance, done with tikz, you can use it to specify the color. For instance, I borrowed from this tex.se thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz 
the following drawing that is similar to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\body}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
  \node[circle,fill,minimum size=5mm] (head) {};
  \node[rounded corners=2pt,minimum height=1.3cm,minimum width=0.4cm,fill,below = 1pt of head] (body) {};
  \draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(2pt,-1pt)}]body.north east) --++(-90:6mm);
  \draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(-2pt,-1pt)}]body.north west)--++(-90:6mm);
  \draw[thick,white,-round cap] (body.south) --++(90:5.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\rowwidth{5}
\def\rownumber{3}
\def\threshold{12}
\parindent 0pt
\foreach \i in {0,...,\rownumber}{
  \foreach \j in {0,...,\rowwidth}{
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse((6*\i+\j>\threshold),"red","blue")}%
    \edef\mycolor{\pgfmathresult}
    \body{color=\mycolor}
  }
  \newline
}
\end{document}
```

The `\edef`allows to save the \pgfmathresult and avoids it to be clobbered.

[image]